# Column_name > " "?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I came across a query today where inside an `IIF` statement there was a comparison where `column > "     "`. I have never seen this before and I am not even sure what it is doing. I am familiar with comparing strings with < and >. IE "B" < "W" returns True.

However what exactly does comparing a column to a string of spaces do?

The line in the select statement:

```
,IIf([CD] > "     " AND [DT]=#12/31/9999#,[MT],[O]) AS [Final]
```

Can someone explain exactly what this comparison is doing and why would you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is checking that `CD` is larger than a field whose name consists only of spaces.  That seems highly unlikely.

My guess is that you are either using MS Access because the date constant is not compatible with SQL Server.  In SQL Server this would be:

```
IIf([CD] > '     ' AND [DT] = #12/31/9999#, [MT], [O]) AS [Final]
```

This is validating that the string does not start with a bunch of spaces.  It is actually a rather pathetic way of doing this; more typically `LTRIM()` would be involved.

I might further speculate that `CD` is exactly five characters long.  In this case, the logic is checking that it is not all spaces.  This would be particularly applicable if the type were `CHAR(5) NOT NULL`.

Comment: Sorry you are correct it is from an access query. I am currently converting all of out access queries into SQL Server queries so we can get rid of access. I should have had Access in my question.

Comment: So would a better way of doing this be `LTRIM([CD])  <> '' `?

Comment: @Mike-SMT . . . I would expect that logic.  The two are not exactly equivalent, but the `LTRIM()` version seems more sensible.